# Is it possible to change the display syntax"Console.WriteLine" in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new in C# programming, can someone tell me on how to change display syntax in C#?

What I would like to output is that instead of:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");//output is "Hello"
```

I will change **Console.WriteLine** to other words, but still its use is for displaying output.

```
 PrintIt("Hello");//output is "Hello"
```

***I wanna use it in textbox and display it in the label. How to do this?***

I'm hoping that you can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can define new procedure `PrintIt()` for that

```
public void PrintIt(string message){
    Console.WriteLine(message);   
}

public static void Main(String []args){
    PrintIt("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Can Create a method like the Guy before me showed you or even u can create a Snippet and then use it every time you start a new project without the need to write the method again.

A code snippet is a block of reusable code that you can insert where you need it in your code. Snippets can be simple or more complex—for example, blocks such as try-finally and if-else are commonly used, but you could also use snippets to insert entire classes or methods.

For instance if you are familiar with the shortcut **ctor** you will know that tapping twice after you wrote that it will generate a constructor for you